# Laravel 5.2: Flash values in session gone after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, laravel-5

I use Laracasts Flash package to display flash messages to my users. But theres a problem: flash values are gone after one redirect. Values wich I set with `Session::set();` are still there. I use the web-middleware on every controller and it even includes the `StartSession` class.
Even redirects`->withInput` are gone after the redirect.

Here's my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $profile = Auth::user()->profile;

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => ['email', 'unique:profiles,email,' . $profile->id, 'max:255'],
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        var_dump("failed");
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->input())->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $profile->update($request->input());
    $profile->save();

    Flash::success('saved');
    \Session::set('test', 'testvalue');
    return redirect()->route('profile.edit');
}
```

Heres the method where I try to get the value:

```
public function edit() {
    $account = Auth::user();

    var_dump(\Session::all());
    return view('profile.edit', [
        'account' => $account,
        'profile' => $account->profile,
    ]);
}
```

The `testvalue` still exists but the flash message is gone. Even if I try to set them myself with `Session::flash();`

Any idea what to do?

Comment: I think flash message are only stored for next request. it will go away after that. you need to store in session if you want to keep it for further use. You can go through https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session to understand flash message behavior

Comment: thanks, but I know how flash messages are working. The problem: its the next request but its still gone.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/15 - this link may help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: Taylor Otwell made some changes at the route service provider. Now every route has the web-middleware applied by default. Assigning it again like I had to before this update (23. March 2016) will discard the flash values.

So: Remove every manual web-middleware assignment. Then It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

The lonely one reason the flash message is gone, it's because it must have more than one redirect, so the data in flash is erased.

Can you try to var_dump like this, only the flash message :

set :

```
Session::flash('success', 'saved');
```

test :

```
var_dump(Session::get('success'));
```

Comment: its "null". I can't explain myself why there should be more than one request.